Power assisted flying control unit

What is the working principle and operation sequence of the power assisted flying control unit?

Please specify what is not already obvious!

It's just the same as power-assisted steering in a motor vehicle or marine vessel.  What did you think might be different?

This hydraulic device is a general design used in many mechanical systems. It relies on two principles:

hydraulic jack
positive feedback loop.

It you prefer video to written explanations, just watch this.
The top section is a valve (a sliding spool four-way directional control valve) injecting pressurized red fluid either on the left or on the right side of the bottom section piston depending on the stick position (it wouldn't work as shown, the pivot between the stick and the valve prevents any translation of the top rod, this pivot must be removed).
The red pressurized fluid entering the bottom cylinder moves the piston, the elevator (or aileron) moves and a positive feedback force is also applied to the stick by the bottom rod, allowing to initiate the displacement with a very small force and let the piston provide the additional force necessary for the action to complete.
As in any jack or hydraulic press, a small input force is converted into a larger one. The gain in magnitude is proportional to the ratio of the areas of the fluid inlet and the piston, explained here.
As the red fluid enters the cylinder on one side of the piston, it must be drained on the other side. Draining is done by connecting the cylinder to the yellow circuit, the control valve is designed to allow these two connections while preventing the red and yellow circuits to be interconnected. Of course the pressure in the yellow circuit must be lower than in the red circuit. The yellow circuit returns the fluid to the tank, it is pressurized again and pumped back into the red circuit.

Good answer.  The diagram may work if the housing moves and the piston is stationary.  (Housing movement is the output).
